# Value of String in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i am making a program that reads words from an external file and then translate them to the corresponding number and then calculate the value .. words calculator !!
i managed to read the words .. convert them into letters .. now i have faced two problems :
1 - i wrote previously another program that reads equations and prints results .. 
when i try to use the same program to give the result for the equation i printed it gives an error that it cant read from that file .. unexpected end of file ..
2 - i tried another approach .. when i read the numbers construct the equation then evaluate it by using the is ..
so ..

```
calculate([Word|Rest],X) :-
    word_to_number(Word,Symbol),
    concat(X,Symbol,NewX),
    calculate(Rest,NewX),
    Result is NewX,
    print(Result),
```

> ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not
>   sufficiently instantiated

now the new concatenated equation is a string and i cant get the value for it .. how can have the value of the string !! and evaluate this equation

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok the answer is :

```
atom_to_term(atom,Term,[]).
```

the string is a term .. for example my equation is '2+1' ..
i send the term to the function .. then i specify the variable i want to save the new value in which is the Term, the third parameter is useless .. just put an empty list .. 
the result is ..

> Term = 2+1 ... then Result is Term.
>   Result is 3.

Done !! After 4 hours of searching !!